# Adding slides of a pdf presentation to the audio file of the same presentation with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, pdftoppm

I want to add slides of a pdf presentation to the audio file of the same presentation with ffmpeg (or whatever).

I split the pdf presentations using pdftoppm into numbered png images and tried to use ffmpeg to sync the audio file with the images. But I am wondering if the output file could be smaller.
Example, the following command will split file 'foo.pdf' into file 'output-01.png', 'output-02.png' etc:

```
$ pdftoppm foo.pdf -png output
```

Then I listen to the audio file 'foo-audio.mp3' and noted the end of each slide in minutes and second. Using a spreadsheet you have to calculate the exact (in seconds) timing of each slide, which can be expressed as 40 for 40 seconds for the program of the conference or 00:01:37 for 1 minute and 37 seconds for your first slide etc and paste it into a text file 'foo-images.txt' which will look like:

```
file ./program.png
duration 40 
file ./output-01.png
duration 00:01:37
```

Then the video can be built with the command:

```
$ ffmpeg -safe 0 -f concat -i foo-images.txt -fps_mode vfr -pix_fmt yuv420p  output.mp4
 height not divisible by 2 (1500x1125)type here
```

but I got the above error that the height was not divisible by 2.
Then I found (on [a the ffmpeg mailing list](https://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2018-October/041725.html)) that I could use the '-vf scale=1680:-2' option and the following command was successful:

```
$ ffmpeg -safe 0 -f concat -i foo-images.txt -vf scale=1680:-2  -pix_fmt yuv420p  output.mp4
```

and in order to sync the audio with the images and get the final video 'foo-video.mp4':

```
$ ffmpeg -safe 0 -f concat -i foo-images.txt -i foo-audio.mp3 -vf scale=1680:-2  -pix_fmt yuv420p  foo-video.mp4
```

It worked, but the video is about 60Mb for 30 slides and 30 minutes presentation. Is is a correct ratio? Although the video can be viewed by an Apple viewer. But is there a benefit to use ffmpeg and command lines compared to the use of softwares like imovie or acrobat to get the same result?
Also I am confused with the scale 1680 (which is fine) and the 420p of pix_fmt.

Comment: Wrong place for this type of FFmpeg question, but the video codec (x264 is the default I think) does not support variable frame rate. `-fps_mode vfr` does not impose variable fps. Use `-r` *output* option to set desired framerate (something low like 10 should suffice for slides) to reduce the file size. Otherwise, study the [wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264)

Comment: x264 does support VFR.  Just add `-i foo-audio.mp3` to the command for output.mp4